# Microsoft Access- How to create dynamic variables that queries a selection of Columns

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

[Example Data Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmEE9.png)

My main data table is constructed in the following way:

```
1.State
2.Product
3.Account Name
4.Jan-20
5.Feb-20
.
.
.
N.)Recent Month- Recent Year
```

My goal is to get 6 total sums based on 6 different contiguous that are user selected. For example, if someone wanted the value of an Account Given a State and Product for FY-2020, they would sum columns 4 to column 15 (Twelve Months).

I am going to be running joins and queries off of the State, Product, Account combinations (first three columns), but I need to create a method to sum the Data table given a list of Column Numbers.

At this point, I am not looking to put non-contiguous columns in a selected Time Period (i.e. all time period selections will be from Col.Beg_TPn to and including Col.End_TPn). The Data Table houses monthly data that will have one new column every month. The Column Number should stay consistent as we are not looking back further than FY-2020.

This a much easier problem in Excel as you can do a simple SumIfs with an Index of the Column Range as the SumRange and then you filter on Columns 1,2,3. My data table is about 30,000 rows, so Excel freezes on me when could calculations and functions on the entire data set.

What is the best way to go about this in Microsoft Access? Ideally, I would like to create a CTE_TimePeriodTotals that houses the First 3 Columns (State,Product,Account) and then 6 TP Columns (tp-1,tp-2...) that holds the sum of each time period for each row based on the Time Period Column Starts and Time Period Column End.

Comment: Can you show some input data and the expected results please.

Comment: Just added. Again, I am just looking for a method that sums a specific Column Range depending on whatever time period the user selects.

Comment: You should start by normalizing your table. Then this calculation should be straightforward using SQL. Excel might be able to solve this as well if you normalize and use a pivot table to filter the time period.

Comment: And by normalizing, we mean reshape your very *wide* format to *long* format since your columns indicate time periods. Particularly true for databases even data analysis maybe not presentation, avoid storing data elements as column headers.

Comment: "6 different contiguous _____ that"? "freezes on me when could calculations"? If you are doing "joins and queries" and data is in Access, why are you using Excel? Are you using Access 2016?

Comment: If you want an all-Access solution, I add my voice to recommendation you normalize data structure, Then pivot with a CROSSTAB query using dynamic PARAMETERS.